# Create a <li> for every image in a folder with a jQuery plugin or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

Is there a way to append a `<ul>` with `<li>` of images from a folder using only javascript? I'm able to create this functionality with server side technology but I wondered if there was some sort of client side technology that would do the magic as well.

I'm wanting to create a gallery of thumbnails without server side programming.

Comment: Where would you get the list of image files from? Unless you can e.g. browse the directory over HTTP and parse the index page I think you'd have to get that list from the server.

Comment: @Rup, yes, I would need to provide some list of some sort in order to achieve this unfortunately. I just wondered if there was a way... without using server technology, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, javascript cannot directly interact with the filesystem (servers or clients). You could potentially create a service you could call via ajax that returns the images, but you will require at least a partial server side solution.

Answer (score 4):

Not without server side code, javascript is a client side language and can not access the file system. Imagine the massive security issues if anyone could run code on against your personal file system!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure thats impossible! even if you use ajax you will still have to have the server side code looking through the images and returning them.

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery code:**

```
$("img").wrap('<li>').wrap('<ul>');
```

this command will search for all image tags and will wrap them with

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <img .....>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: each image gets wrapped in it's own list. Not to mention he has to get a list of the images to begin with. His question implies that he doesn't have img tags created and what's to read the directory to get he image